# how to Add & delete table cell on click of button which is on cell in ios

Tags: ios

I want to add 2 button in table cell one is for + and one is for - ,on clicking of + button i want to add another cell of table view cell containing same + and - 
buttons 
AND on clicking of minus i want to delete last cell of table view 
how to do it ????

Comment: you should add the new cells to your datasource or delete the old cells from your datasource and then you can reload/refresh your `UITableView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581259/sending-reload-data-from-custom-tableview-cell
I found my solution by above link

Comment: This are also help ful link to me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029707/iphone-how-to-determine-in-which-cell-a-button-was-pressed-in-a-custom-uitable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192214/how-to-change-label-text-in-custom-cell-when-button-in-that-cell-clicked